# See if user sent image or not

Tags: php, arrays, file-upload

I have a ***multipar from*** to send images but this images are ***optional*** so if the user dont send an image my code will be false because the ***$_FILE variables*** will be empty.

**What I want is this: If their is an image execute the code below if not do nothing**

```
if(isset($_FILES['file_array'])){    
    $imageName = $_FILE['file_array']['name'] ;
    $imageTempName = $_FILE['file_array']['tmp_name'] ;
    $imageBlob = file_get_contents($_FILE['file_array']['tmp_name']) ;
    $imageSize = $_FILE['file_array']['size'] ;
}
```

Thank you very much!!

Comment: check using `isset($_FILES['file_array']['name']`.

Comment: yes just using if and empty?? i guess yes i not that hard sorry

Comment: by using them you can detect that user upload a photo or not, if them you need to `move_uploaded_file`. Check with what i suggest.

Comment: Nop is not working, maybe with a simple image but in this case is with multiple images in an array

Answer (score 0):

## Your solution

You can use something like `mime_content_type()` to check if a file is an image.

Perhaps something like

```
if (stripos(mime_content_type($_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name']), "image") !== FALSE) {
    // Image sent.
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but im not trying to check the type of the file I trying to know if they sent an image or not!

Comment: Which in your case, my code would work perfectly, checks if they sent an image or not!